# AIR for Android, Flash iphone packager, Playbook support for streaming camera and choosing camera

Tags: iphone, android, flash, blackberry, air

I am wondering if anyone can definitively tell me if Flash / AIR can find all these mobile devices front facing camera and use RTMP to stream the video captured ?

I would like to create a video conferencing app for these devices. Of course none of them support testing this in the simulators and I don't have the funds to purchase or access all of them that I would like to test.

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this for me. I have seen some posts where they have done this for android but not sure about support for finding a list of cameras, choosing one and streaming from iphone 4 and playbook.

thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered, current AIR features vary depending on the platform:

1) iPhone - no access to camera for video chat yet

2) Android - single camera access only (on dual cam devices, only access the rear cam)

3) Playbook - supposed to allow access to both cameras according to Blackberry forums

My ReelPortal app currently runs on Android devices with a single front cam (Archos 70/101, Viewsonic gTablet, eLocity A7), and PC/Mac/Linux. I already submitted a version for the Playbook, but won't find out if it works until the device is released. I believe Flash support is even less (no camera/microphone access on Android).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/868/cpsid_86822.html about android

> CameraUI still picture and video
>   This feature allows you to access a
>   phone's camera application. Once the
>   user takes a picture or video the
>   saved media is saved to camera roll
>   and returned to ActionScript through a
>   MediaEvent. Note tht the video format
>   returned by the camera application may
>   not be a format that can be played in
>   an AIR application.

There is no mention of rtmp streaming the recorded video, so I assume it is not available.